# desfire command set detail

Tags: mifare

I have experience in java cards, but new in programming host application for Desfire,
How or Where can I find command set description of Desfire?
(I do not need general information like what NXP has mentioned in It's "Product short data sheet"s),
I need the commands Instruction code and parameter details and responses (Like APDU or something).
thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am having exact same trouble as you. The closest thing to documentation of the commands is a blog post that shows a couple of examples of what the desfire communication looks like.

http://ridrix.wordpress.com/2009/09/19/mifare-desfire-communication-example/`

But there is a library that can help you with putting desfire commands together:

http://code.google.com/p/nfc-tools/wiki/libfreefare

Edit: It turns out that you can't get the documentation freely. You need to sign an NDA and then buy it.

Comment: Thank you for your help,
 I have expected to pay for such documentation,
 but I've not it found yet.
 I'd like you address where can I buy that.

Comment: First you need to send this request to NXP: http://www.nxp.com/documents/other/mf_passwordrequest200902.pdf

Comment: Ridrix blog is quite outdated. You find newer examples. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283998/desfire-ev1-communication-examples/38283999#38283999

Answer (score 5):

Very complete command send can be found from this Host Card Emulation project. It shows how to emulate a DESFire card on Android mobile:

- https://github.com/jekkos/android-hce-desfire/blob/master/hceappletdesfire/src/main/java/net/jpeelaer/hce/desfire/DesFireInstruction.java

I found this PDF useful (third party list of commands for older model) - it can you get started with things like getting application list:

http://neteril.org/files/M075031_desfire.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11469944)

Comment: @FabioLamanna: Thank you for the comment. DESFire command set is 100+ pages so there is a reason why it is not included in the answer.

Comment: @FabioLamanna: I'll see if I can get a summary in the answer, written in a manner it doesn't violate any NDAs are copyrights. It's an interface after all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to buy it, the datasheets are free after you sign the NDA and NXP sets you up to download the secure documentation.