# Recommending safe softwares for DESFire manager ChangeKeySettings, changeKeys, changeFileSetting ,FormatPICC?

Tags: mifare, contactless-smartcard

In DESFire command set [see DESFire datasheet](http://neteril.org/files/M075031_desfire.pdf) , we have some commands like ChangeFileSettings, ChangeKey, ChangeKeySettings, FormatPICC etc.

I want to configure my DESFire cards by a configuration software but I don't know any software.

Comment: take a look at this question also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174000/desfire-command-set-detail

Comment: useful: http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/161/desfire-authentication/ and

Comment: The link comming above(I means this : [link](http://libnfc.org/community/topic/161/desfire-authentication) Is for doing DES in C language?

Comment: The line just before the code: _If you want to play with this, here is a copy-paste of the *development* code related to Mifare DESFire authentication I am using_.

Comment: And yes, it is written in C language. I didn't test it although.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a some tools and libraries that you can use for you goal :

1. [Mifare DESFire EV1 Tool for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skjolberg.mifare.desfiretool)
2. [NFC-Tools/Libfreefare](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libfreefare)
3. [DESFire Tools](https://github.com/henryk/desfire-tools)

Anyway, a tool is provided by NXP also. But you need to first sign an NDA, and then buy it, so I think it is better to write a proprietary program for yourself.