# Getting the UID/serial number of an NXP MIFARE DESFire EV1 card

Tags: uwp, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard, serial-number

I'm currently making a project where I want to use my Windows 10 phone featuring NFC to read the UID/serial number of a smart card to find the ID of a person. The card I'm trying to get the UID/serial number from is an NXP MIFARE DESFire EV1. The ID I'm looking for is printed on the card and I managed to access it using my friend's phone with an Android app which means that the number is accessible although I don't know how.

I'm able to send APDU commands to the card but I don't know which one to use to get the UID/serial number I'm looking for.

What APDU commands do I need to send to the card to obtain the ID? The ID I'm looking for is 7 bytes long.

Comment: Sorry, reading of non-smart cards is strongly dependent on the translation services of reader and you did not mention one. You may find a starting point in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12174000/1435475).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general retrieving parameters such as the anti-collision identifier (UID) of contactless cards depends very much on the reader and the abstraction layers between the reader and your application. For instance, on Android there is a simple method `getId()` to get the anti-collision identifier of an NFC tag/contactless smartcard.

However, for MIFARE DESFire there is also a way to obtain that parameter by means of APDUs. You can simply send a GET VERSION command to query version information (and also the card UID):

```
C-APDU: 90 60 0000 00
R-APDU: 04 01 YY 01 00 ZZ 05 91AF

C-APDU: 90 AF 0000 00
R-APDU: 04 01 01 01 04 ZZ 05 91AF

C-APDU: 90 AF 0000 00
R-APDU: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX UUUUUUUUUU VV WW 9100
```

The value `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the UID of the card (or all zeros if the card is in random anti-collision identifier mode).

Note that there even exists a parser for the MIFARE DESFire version information [here](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api/blob/master/externalNFCClient/src/main/java/com/skjolberg/nfc/desfire/VersionInfo.java) (as [ThomasRS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459579/thomasrs) pointed out in a comment).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for your precious time. You have no idea how helpful for me amd for others this is going to be. I'll never forget you

Comment: Parser at https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api/blob/master/externalNFCClient/src/main/java/com/skjolberg/nfc/desfire/VersionInfo.java