# Programming Access Control Cards

Tags: smartcard, access-control, mifare, contactless-smartcard, wiegand

My question is regarding PAC (personal access control), more specifically programming a card. I am not trying to create any applications or interfaces, rather just putting the basic required data into a "blank" DESFire card using the wiegand format.

For example, I want to write to a card the following:
o   Card UID
o   Facility Code
o   Sequence number (e.g. 500 – 699)
o   etc.

How do i do this?... What program do I use? I have a Pegoda EV710 reader with the RFIDiscover software, I have another kit from Smart Toolz here as well but these things just seem way too much for the basic task that I'm trying to do. Do most folk create their own application to do this for them?

Am i way off the mark here? Can it be done using what I have? Is there more data that needs to be on the card per the AN10957 document here?
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10957.pdf

I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I somewhat lost, what *wiegand* has to contribute here. From what I see from the data sheet, the reader should be fine, the problem seems to be a gap of know-how/documentation. For a start look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12174000/1435475). Some would also challenge, whether DESFire can be considered as a smart card.

Comment: DESFire specific cards are arguably not a smart card, I'd consider it a *memory* card. Smart Cards should be programmable, and DESFire is not. DESFire could be implemented *on* a Smart Card of course - and NXP has done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for DESFire EV1 you probably can use APDU´s to Create Applications and write Files into. You may need a NDA with NXP to get the full docu.

So far I can tell you the common process, for more details see the documentation of your reader or used sdk.

The following process for Create-Application:

```
 1. CreateApplication - 0xCA
 2. SelectApplication - 0x5A
 3. CreateStandardDataFiles - 0xCD
 4. ChangeKeys (Default-Key all 00s) - 0xC4
 5. Authenticate - 0x0A, 0x1A, 0xAA
 6. WriteStandardData - 0x3D
```

FEIG does have a simple SDK for DESFire and the CPR40.30 reader. For me this was a good start to learn.

On APDU level the Authentication is a complex process to verify that both sides have the same key.

Comment: You may want to see this post: https://www.mifare.net/support/forum/topic/mifare-desfire-authentication/